# How to make an archive if there are two target in my apps

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, plist, archive

Friends!

I am creating archive file of my application and then creating ipa and plist file of it for sharing it.

But if there are two targets in my application, I can't create plist and ipa file for enterprise. I am getting the screen shown in image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got my answer by :

http://astralbodies.net/blog/2011/03/27/xcode-4-problem-submitting-app-with-static-library/

**it is showing:**

1) Click on the Core Plot project which should be a child of your App’s project.

2) Click on the Project CorePlot-CocoaTouch and go to the Build Settings.  Set “Skip Install” to Yes.

3) Click on the CorePlot-CocoaTouch target and set “Skip Install” to Yes.

4) Click Build Phases and under Copy Headers, move all of the Public and Private entries to the Project section.

Answer (score 0):

Did you Set a configuration for your Archive scheme? If not, please do it in the following way.

In the drop down menu in your tool bar next to the Run and Stop button, select Edit Scheme. Select Archive in the left pane and then set the Build Configuration to your Release and add the Archive Name then click OK.

Comment: i have already done it , it is working for me with single target , but if  i am using multiple target (static library) it is not working in and showing as shown in image.